# jQuery highlight one at a time

Tags: jquery, foreach, highlight

I'm trying to add a class to an `li` element once after `button` is clicked.
The goal is to add the class one at a time with a delay time in between. It seems to work fine with the `fadeOut` function but not with the `addClass` or related function.

Here is a Jsfiddle.net demo http://jsfiddle.net/4ANCj/3/

and part of the code

```
$("button").click(function() {
    $('li').each(function(index) {
        $(this).delay(900*index).addClass("hi");
    });
});
```

I know there is a [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6566861/jquery-show-one-element-at-a-time) question here on SO but it does not cut it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`addClass` is not an animation function, so it is not added to the effect queue. You can use [`.queue` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/queue/) instead (adds to the effect queue by default):

```
$(this).delay(900*index).queue(function(next) {
    $(this).addClass("hi");
    next();
});
```

Or use [`setTimeout` *<sup>[MDN]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout) for a non-jQuery solution:

```
$("button").click(function() {
    var lis = $('li').get();

    function run() {
        var li;
        if(li = lis.shift()) {
            $(li).addClass('hi');
            setTimeout(run, 900);
        }
    }

    setTimeout(run, 900);
});
```

Comment: Awesome. I did not know about `queue`. Thanks a lot.

Comment: nice. How would I implement `removeClass` after it has run, something simple I think is creating a problem..

Comment: When and how to you want to call `removeClass`? On all elements at once or after a certain time the element has the class?